# Cutting an arbitrary object into equal sized pieces

Tags: measure-theory

Not homework, this problem occurred to me while chopping vegetables.

Consider an arbitrary object in $\mathbb{R}^n$, is it possible to cut it into $2^n$ pieces of equal volume using $n$ orthogonal slices?  Suppose that the volume of the original object is $2^n$ so I want want each piece to have volume $1$,

If the object has sufficient symmetry, e.g. a sphere or a cube, then it is easy.  I would like to consider arbitrary objects, my tomatoes are not sufficiently symmetric.

Various reasonable conditions may be assumed.  Measurabuility is an obvious requirement.  Boundedness if necessary but if it would be nice if it wasn't.  Similarly, connectedness if necessary but again it would be nice if it wasn't; obviously the answer might not be unique for non-connected objects but that is acceptable.

For $n = 1$, the problem is easy.

For $n = 2$, possible but a little more care is needed.  First, we can slice it along a line with constant $x$ into two equal pieces.  Now do the same with a line with constant $y$.  We have 4 pieces but they are not necessarily all equal.  Diagonally opposite pieces must be equal but adjacent ones need not be.  However, I can now rotate my cuts and solve that.

For $n = 3$, it gets harder.  I can start similarly with planes of constant $x$, $y$, and $z$ followed by rotations but I don't seem to have sufficient degrees of freedom to balance all 8 pieces.

I have not attempted $n > 3$ yet, let's walk before I can run.  Anyway, I don't have any $4d$ tomatoes.

Comment: Your "I can rotate my cuts and solve that" in the 2D case is pretty ... uh... optimistic. I mean, with nice enough hypotheses it's probably true, but it's certainly not trivial. There's an area of topology that in the old Steenrod Index was called "Kakutani-Yamabe-Yojubo Theorems" (where I may have mis-spelled some or all names here), and these tended to address just the kind of things you're asking. One such theorem says that a convex object in 3-space can always be tightly packed (i.e. touching all six sides) in some cubical box. :)

Comment: Thanks.  I am assuming measurability (otherwise my question makes no sense).  Here were my thoughts: make my initial cuts with lines parallel to the axes.  I now have four segments: $a_{11}, a_{12}, a_{21}, a_{22}$ with $a_{11} + a_{12} = a_{21} + a_{22}$ and $a_{11} + a_{21} = a_{12} + a_{22}$ which implies $a_{11} = a_{22}$ and $a_{12} = a_{21}$.  Now rotate the cuts by $\theta$.  I had expected that the sector sizes would be continuous functions of $\theta$.  When $\theta = \pi/2$ the large and small segments are exchanged.  Hence by the IVT, there is a point at which they were equal.

Comment: Well, the sector sizes *might* be continuous functions of rotation. Perhaps the right hypothesis is this: let $M$ be the shape to be chopped up and let $G$ be the (topological) group of isometries of 3-space, and consider the action of $G$ on the complement of the union of the coordinate  hyperplanes (i.e., the quadrants or octants or whatever...) For each such octant $q$ and group element $g$, let $A(g, q) = vol(g(q) \cap M)$. We **assume** that for each octant $q$, $g \mapsto A(g, q)$ is continuous function on $G$. Now you're all set up for a K-Y-Y type of theorem (i.e., generalized IVT).

Comment: I expect it can be done for n=2 and not for n=3 but I have a hard time pin pointing where this intuition is coming from. One example of a sort-of-similar question where the answer is 2 for n=2 and no for n=3 is whether you can cut-and-paste any polygonal shape into any other polygonal shape of the same volume (that is: decompose the first shape in finitely many measurable pieces and put them together after rotation and shifting to form the other shape). Both the positive result in n=2 and the negativein n =3 are not easy to prove, though and it's completely different from your question.

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks again.  You have given this old brain something to think about but that was the point of the exercise.  You just assume the necessary continuity, can you think of a possible counterexample?

Comment: I cannot think of a counterexample, but I'm not so good at measure theory/analysis stuff. My guess is that something unbounded is the right place to look. If you stick with, say, $M$ compact and measurable, I suspect you get continuity for free (but I can't prove it, because it's been too long since I proved ANYthing about measure/continuity).

Comment: @Vincent Thanks.  That fits my thoughts so far.  Modulo John Hughes's comments, it can be done for $n = 2$.  In $n = 3$, as I said, I don't seem to have sufficiently many degrees of freedom to balance all 8 segments.  I have not tried $n = 4$ yet, I would need to check the rotation group first.  At a guess, it will be even worse than then $n = 3$.

Comment: For $n = 3$, you need to achieve 7 equalities (the first octant's contents are equal to those of the other 7). The isometry group looks like $E_3$ (translations) times $SO(3)$ (rotations) which is only six dimensional. So on just a dimension-counting basis, it seems unlikely to be true. But I don't see an instant counterexample, alas.

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks again.  I suspect that it is even longer since I attempted a formal proof in this area.  I would be happy to accept bounded or compact but it is nice to explore the limits of an idea.

Comment: @JohnHughes Yes, that's what I meant by not having sufficient degrees of freedom: 3d of translations and 3d of rotations.  I have also not yet found a specific counterexample.  Anyway, I am pleased that I have not missed something trivial and obvious.